# Solve differential equation $y' = |1.1 - y| + 1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

How can the following differential equation be solved analytically?

\begin{equation*}
y' = |1.1 - y| + 1, \\ 
y(0) = 1.
\end{equation*}

I guess one must rewrite the differential equation piecewise and solve each piece independently. But how and how do I continue?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: First of all, any solution is strictly increasing as $y^\prime \geq 1$. So that you only have two pieces to stitch together, before and after some value $x^\ast > 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving the two differentail equations in Paul's post yields:

\begin{equation*}y(x) = 2.1 - 1.1e^{-x},|1.1−y| > 0 \end{equation*} and

\begin{equation*}y(x) = e^{x} + 0.1, |1.1−y| < 0 .\end{equation*}

Answer (score 4):

Break the time into 2 periods.

(1) Initially, the argument of the absolute value is positive.  In this case, you get

$$y'=2.1-y$$
which can be solved by standard methods.

(2) When you get a solution here, find out at what time $y=1.1$ (call that time $t_0$).  At $t_0$ there will be a change in behavior.  $y'$ will still be positive, so immediately thereafter, the argument of the absolute value will be negative, so
$$y'=y-0.1$$
with initial condition $y(t_0)=1.1$.  This in turn can be solved normally.  And since $y'>0$ for all $t>t_0$, you don't have to worry about crossing $y = 1.1$ again.  So you only have 2 periods to work with, and this gives you the solution.